# Do function arguments of an outer function change for an asynchronous inner function?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, arguments, closures

I am confused in this topic which is important to me in terms of asynchronous function calls and closures. I must have missed the most important part of javascript function invocation and wasn't able to find an answer to my question up to now, hence I hope for your help!

My question assumes:

1. An outer function `fDynamic` is called with some argument `i` ( = 0 )
2. `fDynamic` queues an inner function `fInnerQueued`, to be invoked at some point in time in the future.
3. In the mean time the outer function `fDynamic` is invoked again with different argument  `i` ( = 1 )

Is this new argument value now visible to the first inner function `fInnerQueued` which will see the changes as soon as it is finally invoked? ... it seems not?

It seems as if the function arguments are not free variables and are bound tightly to the function invocation scope even trough asynchronous calls.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dominicbosch/3Tq2r/14/) and here the essence:

```
var j = 0;
var fDynamic = function( i ) {
  j = i; // j seems to be a free variable, while i is not?
  if( i == 0 ) {
    // Delay execution in order to let i change to 1
    var fInnerQueued = function() {
      console.log(i + ' ('+ j + ')'); //should be "1 (1)" but is "0 (1)"
    }
    setTimeout( fInnerQueued, 100);
  } else {
    console.log(i); // is "1 (1)", right!
  }
}; // Expected output "1 (1)", "1 (1)" but it is "1 (1)", "0 (1)"...
fDynamic(0);
fDynamic(1);
```

I tested it also on node.js and got the same, somewhat unexpected, output.

I crawled through different posts and didn't manage to find an answer:

- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111200#111200) & [How does the outer function "store" the arguments for the inner function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035679/how-does-the-outer-function-store-the-arguments-for-the-inner-function): not explained in the asynchronous context
- [accessing outer caller function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130813/accessing-outer-caller-function-arguments): also not in the asynchronous context
- [Understanding closures: Constructing a meta-function that queues functions together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605325/understanding-closures-constructing-a-meta-function-that-queues-functions-toget): Went into the right direction but still the arguments of the outer function do not change in this question.

I know I can omit the hassle by creating shielded closures or using bind. But I really want to understand why function arguments are not considered free variables to inner functions and they are even retained through asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function arguments are locally scoped variables.

```
function foo (x) {

}
foo(1);
```

is roughly the same as

```
function foo () {
    var x = 1;
}
foo();
```

not

```
function foo () {
    x = 1;
}
foo();
```

The argument is closed over when you use an inner function.

Calling the function again creates a new variable in a new scope.

Comment: so each call creates a new scope? I thought functions are like instances which share the same scope through different invocations. That's something I didn't need to think about when only using synchronous stuff.

Comment: Yes. Each function call creates its own scope.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple: `i` is a function context variable, when the parser finished parsing the function it's deleted. `j` is a variable in the global context and therefore it isn't deleted when the function exits.

When you call the function twice, a new context is created for each call and `i` is in this since `i` isn't a class variable but a parameter. The first time you call it, the 'old' context is preserved so that your child function can execute in a child context, in which `i` is still 0. When this happens the `i` of the second call is already gone, only `j` in the global context is preserved.

Comment: So you're telling me the parser runs over the function each time it is invoked? That's interesting to know. Since I somewhat thought it would reduce the parser's workload by defining functions in the global context. If he anyways parses them just before invocation I can pull them in as close to the call as I see fits.

Comment: And yeah I guess it's simple if you know how the engine works ;) I hoped it's be a simple and logic answer though. just couldn't find the answer anywhere up to now.

Comment: It's not actually parsing, it creates a context. A context is some kind of a 'list' containing all current variables and is to separate them. Without it, parameter `i` in function a would collide with your iteration variable `i` in function b. Scope means all current affected contexts.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference whether you calling function synchronous or async way (e.g. via setTimeout) as Quentin correctly point out

> Function arguments are locally scoped variables.

Please see [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sejoker/3Tq2r/17/) (fStatic is called 2 times for parity with fDynamic)

```
appendLog("Static Argument, changed within function (expected: 0, 1, 0, 1):");
var fStatic = function( i ) {
var fPrintArg = function() {
 appendLog( i );
};
setTimeout(fPrintArg, 100);
fPrintArg();
}; 
fStatic(0);
fStatic(1);
```

the results are the same: i var is scoped for each outer function call.